# How to query in a Flutter/FirebaseAnimatedList using buildArguments or anything else? (example please)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dart, flutter

I have a this `Scaffold` with body:

```
body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Flexible(
            child: new FirebaseAnimatedList(
              query: FirebaseDatabase.instance
                  .reference()
                  .child('products')
                  .orderByChild('order'),
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              reverse: false,
              itemBuilder: (_, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                  Animation<double> animation, int x) {
                return new ProductItem(
                    snapshot: snapshot, animation: animation);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

but I need to add a simple query:  `'Active' = true`

Is it possible? How? Any example/tutorial?

Thanks.

Comment: Since you want to query by 'active' field, your query should look like `FirebaseDatabase.instance .reference().child('active').equalTo(true)` or `FirebaseDatabase.instance .reference().child('active').equalTo('true')` depending on the way you store active field. May I know what is the motive for using orderByChild('order')? Why is part of the query?

Comment: @ChennaReddy, I need the resulting query order by 'order' which is a integer field (or attribute) that some admin users can change (update). So final users can see data ordered by 'order' (but only 'Active'=true as you help me to solve).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If I am getting your question correctly, you are trying to query some data where ("Active" = true), then see the following example.

I have added a screenshot from my db to have more context on the way my data is structured and hopefully it will put you into perspective to implement something similar on your end.

[image]

In the previous example, I am doing the following query to only obtain contact of email set to "em1@gmail.com" while neglecting the others.

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Firebase Example"),),
      body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Flexible(
            child: new FirebaseAnimatedList(
                query: FirebaseDatabase.instance
                    .reference().child("contacts")
                    .orderByChild("email")
                    .startAt("em1@gmail.com").endAt("em1@gmail.com"),
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                reverse: false,
                itemBuilder: (_, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                    Animation<double> animation, int x) {
                  return new ListTile(
                    subtitle: new Text(snapshot.value.toString()),
                  );
                }
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Hope it helped.

P.S: As [Chenna Reddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/808877/chenna-reddy) pointed out, you can replace `startAt("em1@gmail.com").endAt("em1@gmail.com")` by `equalTo("em1@gmail.com")`

`startAt` and `endAt` are useful when you need to limit your query to a certain range.

[For more information.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#filtering_data)

Comment: Why not use `equalTo` instead of combination of `startAt` and `endAt`?

Comment: This is how I initially set up my query, `equalTo` will definitely have the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, following your guide (@ChennaReddy and @aziza), this is the way I fix my code:

```
body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Flexible(
            child: new FirebaseAnimatedList(
              query: FirebaseDatabase.instance
                  .reference()
                  .child('products')
                  .orderByChild('Active')           // line changed
                  .equalTo(true),                   // line added
              padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              reverse: false,
              itemBuilder: (_, DataSnapshot snapshot,
                  Animation<double> animation, int x) {
                return new ProductItem(
                    snapshot: snapshot, animation: animation);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

However, I need the resulting query order by 'order' which is a integer field (or attribute) that some admin users can change (update).  So final users can see data ordered by 'order' (but only 'Active'=true as you help me to solve).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was facing similar situation and your answer helped but raised antoher question. How can i make it scroll with the list, instead of a static widget sitting at top ?