# How to search text in Flutter using Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to implement search functionality using cloud Firestore by a query but not getting any query related to fetch data. I have searched many things on google but everywhere the only suggestion is first to get all data from cloud Firestore then searches locally. I have checked the where condition inside of the query but not finding any condition like "start with" etc.

[image]

I want to search by the name parameter.

[image]

Comment: Do you want to search for documents where the `name` field exactly matches the search term or do you want to a full text search (https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search) ?

Comment: Thanks for response
 suppose I have many records so if I have searched the "al" so all text will show who starts with and matches with "al" text.

Comment: Okay, that's a full-text search. Please visit the link in my first comment to see how it is implemented. You will need a third-party search service like Algolia.

Comment: I have checked the URL as you suggest but can't understand this if you have any demo related to this so please share with me.
And I have also searched the (https://pub.dev/packages/firestore_search) plugin so can you please suggest is use full or not.

Comment: Checkout https://dev.to/samarthagarwal/full-text-search-in-flutter-with-algolia-3kni for the demo.

Answer (score 18):

Firestore does not have built-in full-text-search capabilities. The only two query operators I commonly use for searching text fields are:

- Using `isEqualTo:` to find documents where the field matches the value exactly.
- Using `isGreaterThanOrEqualTo:` and `isLessThanOrEqualTo:` (or `startAt:` and `endAt:`) to search for documents where the field starts with a specific value.

  For example, to search for all documents where `name` starts with `al`,
  you'd use `collectionRef.where("name", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: "al").where("name", isLessThanOrEqualTo: "al\uf7ff")`. The `\uf7ff` here is just the last known Unicode character, so that the query stops returning results after dealing with every `al`.

If you want any other text search operations, you'll need to use an additional product for that - such the ones for which the process is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search).

Answer (score 5):

**this code will be very super helpful in searching text by using firestone flutter**

```
 StreamBuilder(
    stream: ( searchtxt!= "" && searchtxt!= null)?FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("addjop").where("specilization",isNotEqualTo:searchtxt).orderBy("specilization").startAt([searchtxt,])
        .endAt([searchtxt+'\uf8ff',])
        .snapshots()
        :FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("addjop").snapshots(),
    builder:(BuildContext context,snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting &&
          snapshot.hasData != true) {
        return Center(
            child:CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      }
      else
        {retun widget();
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

for firebase searching in the docs with a `String query`

```
collectionRef.where(
      'name',
      isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: query.isEmpty ? 0 : query,
      isLessThan: query.isEmpty
          ? null
          : query.substring(0, query.length - 1) +
              String.fromCharCode(
                query.codeUnitAt(query.length - 1) + 1,
              ),
    )
    .snapshots()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way for short strings like a name. We use it quite often in our apps. You can split the name into small parts and add them to an array. To search for the name with a full text search wait to have at least 3 letters and check then if the combination of letters is part of the array using the `array-contains-any` query.

The split to array code:

```js
const MAPPING_TABLE = {
  à: 'a',
  á: 'a',
  â: 'a',
  ã: 'a',
  å: 'a',
  æ: 'ae',
  ç: 'c',
  è: 'e',
  é: 'e',
  ê: 'e',
  ë: 'e',
  ì: 'i',
  í: 'i',
  î: 'i',
  ï: 'i',
  ñ: 'n',
  ò: 'o',
  ó: 'o',
  ô: 'o',
  õ: 'o',
  ù: 'u',
  ú: 'u',
  û: 'u',
  ý: 'y',
  ÿ: 'y',
}

function splitStringToArray(stringToSplit) {
  const listCharacters = stringToSplit.split('')
  var output = []
  //replace special Characters
  for (var i = 0; i < listCharacters.length; i++) {
    if (MAPPING_TABLE[listCharacters[i]] != null) {
      listCharacters[i] = MAPPING_TABLE[listCharacters[i]]
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < listCharacters.length; i++) {
    var temp = [listCharacters[i]]
    for (var j = i + 1; j < listCharacters.length; j++) {
      temp.push(listCharacters[j])
      const joinedString = temp.join('').toLowerCase()
      if (joinedString.length > 2) {
        output.push(joinedString)
      }
    }
  }
  return output
}

export default splitStringToArray
```

And here is a query to search for the name:

```js
ref = ref.where("search", "array-contains-any", [value.toLowerCase()]);

const snap = await ref.limitToLast(20).get();
```

I would also limit the results to a realisting amount of elements.