# How to check if firestore document field CONTAINS a string

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uisearchbar

Basically, I want to use UISearchBar to filter out documents in a collection in a tableview. When the user finishes putting text inside the search bar, the code should fire a query to get the documents only if it contains given text.

For example, **User searches: "Th"**

What could output in the uitableview:

> this
>
> the
>
> them
>
> one thing
>
> breath

This should work no matter where "Th" is within the document field, however I am unsure how to implement this. Like e.g. should I use `.whereField(field, isGreaterThan: searchedText)`? I don't really know.

Comment: Searching strings that start with the query is straightforward Firestore. However, searching for string segments within a string is definitely not.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Firestore currently doesn't support native indexing or search for text fields in documents. To enable full text search of your Cloud Firestore data, use a dedicated third-party search service such as [Algolia](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search)

However, As mentioned in [similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68226813/18265570) it supports two query operators for searching text fields which starts substring

I.e. Using `isEqualTo`,  `isGreaterThanOrEqualTo` and `isLessThanOrEqualTo`

For example, to search for all documents where name starts with “Th”, you'd use `collectionRef.where("name", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: "Th").where("name", isLessThanOrEqualTo: "Th\uf7ff")`. The `\uf7ff` here is just the last known Unicode character, so that the query stops returning results after dealing with every “Th”

**Note:** There is no way to search for documents which contain a substring, nor for those whose text ends with a substring.

For other alternative solution you can refer this [link](https://medium.com/feedflood/filter-by-search-keyword-in-cloud-firestore-query-638377bf0123)