# Flutter | how to retrieve a list of objects from firestore?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I need to retrieve this list "items" from firestore [this the structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7qeh.png)
by this code

```
Future<void> fetchCategories(String userId) async {
return databaseReference
    .collection('/categories/$userId/cats/')
    .snapshots()
    .listen((data) {
  data.documents.forEach((doc) {
    categories.add(Category(
      id: doc.documentID,
      items:   ,
      title: doc.data['title'],
    ));
  });
});
```

and "items" property is a list of CategoryItem objects

```
 class CategoryItem {
   String id;
   String title;
   String imageUrl;
   String description;

  CategoryItem({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    this.imageUrl,
    @required this.description,
  });

  CategoryItem.fromMap(Map<String,Object> data):
    id=data['id']??'',
    title=data['title']??'',
    imageUrl=data['imageUrl']??'',
    description=data['description']??'';

}
```

Comment: Hi, You can use `FirebaseAnimatedList` widget to propagate data easily. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46912713/how-to-query-in-a-flutter-firebaseanimatedlist-using-buildarguments-or-anything

Comment: @Blasanka Hello , thanks for replying , but for some reasons i need to retrieve my data first then display it in a custom list view , so i need my data first , this is my problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this is the answer

```
Future<void> fetchCategories(String userId) async {
    return databaseReference
        .collection('/categories/$userId/cats/')
        .snapshots()
        .listen((data) {
      data.documents.forEach((doc) {
        categories.add(Category(
          id: doc.documentID,
          items:  [...(doc.data['items']).map((items){return CategoryItem.fromMap(items);})],
          title: doc.data['title'],
        )); 
      });
    });


class CategoryItem {
   String id;
   String title;
   String imageUrl;
   String description;

  CategoryItem({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    this.imageUrl,
    @required this.description,
  });

  CategoryItem.fromMap(Map<dynamic,dynamic> data):
    id=data['id']??'',
    title=data['title']??'',
    imageUrl=data['imageUrl']??'',
    description=data['description']??'';

}
```

Comment: great you found the answer. One thing, You dont have to expand the list `...`, just add `.toList()` to you map function. `map((items){return CategoryItem.fromMap(items);}).toList()`

Comment: @Blasanka ty ^_^